# ASP.NET Team Development

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, version-control

I have been developing ASP.NET projects SOLO, now I have a project where I will be working with two other developer. Other two developer will be working with me on the same project remotely.

Tools What we will be using..

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition
- MS SQL Server 2012
- Microsoft MVC 3.0 FrameWork
- Microsoft IIS 7.0

I will be mostly working on Models and Controllers, Other two developers will be actively involved building VIEWS and some teaks within controllers as well. In other words, pretty much all the files will be available to all 3 of us to make changes anytime.

I don't know whats the best approach where we can work as a team, and edit each other files and see changes on our LIVE STAGING/TEST SERVER.

I have heard of source safe programs but never used any, is this what I need? if yes then any FREE out there for using them remotely?

In other words, I need a simple yet effective approach to work on a project as a team, where all team members are working remotely. Only approach I know is "FTP", where all of us FTP Files to same WebServer, but this leaves us a lot of room of overwriting each other work.

Comment: [Distributed Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) FTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Foundation Service is free, and no server setup/domain membership is required. Up to 5 can connect for free.  http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

There is also Team Foundation Express, which has similar limitations to SQL Server Express, since that is what it uses for storage.  Using this will require some more difficult setup, as you need to be able to dynamically register an IP or get a static IP address from your Internet provider, as well as configurations to allow other users to connect and/or VPN into a server.  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-express

Both are tightly integrated with VS 2012, and are backward compatible with 2010 if you install SP1 and a GDR update, though you will need 2012 to configure projects.  Both TFS options come with a free 2012 shell to do this configuration.

Comment: TFS makes sense, I created an account with it. I have VS 2010 with SP1, i also installed GDR update. However my "Team Explorer" menu within VS is very limited, I dont see any options (Such as HOME, set working directory etc). any reasons why?

Comment: Because those options don't exist in TFS.

Comment: You should really clarify 'TFS,' as it originally stood for 'Team Foundation Server' (pre-cloud), and is now also used for 'Team Foundation Service' (cloud).  Some things are not available with the cloud version, and some things are still being ironed out by Microsoft for the future.  Everything available in the cloud version is currently free until they implement and analyze the various features.  Click the 'pricing' link on that site to see what is available and what is planned.

Comment: @highwingers, VS 2010 is limited.  Both TFS 2012 versions are tightly integrated with VS 2012.  For VS 2010, you have to open Team Explorer and click on 'Source Control' at the bottom of the connected server.  This opens the 'Source Control' Window, where you should be able to map and get latest.  It is very different from VS 2012.  You can always install the VS 2012 shell and manage things from there, but I understand why you wouldn't want to.  here's how to setup the cloud version with 2012: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/connect-vs

Answer (score 1):

you can use tortoise svn which comes for free and setups are easily available 
http://tortoisesvn.net/

It is very good for primary purposes which is only and only source contro.check ins ,check outs.but If you want to do some advanced things such as maintaining bugs,tracking progress.generate reports.Use Team foundation server which is licensed by microsoft